# Why was my Google+ custom URL not approved?

Tags: google-plus

Google offered me a custom URL, but it's not significantly easier to type than the number string:
`google.com/+TorbenGundtofteBruun` is still longer than the one I currently use:
`torben.g-b.dk/+`  so I requested to use my online handle that I use practically *everywhere:* `google.com/+torbengb`. This request was denied today (see below) but it doesn't state any reason so I don't know what alternatives I could try. Of course I've already [googled for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=why%20was%20my%20Google%2b%20custom%20URL%20not%20approved) but didn't find useful information.

Can anybody shed some light on the matter?

---

[image]

Comment: maybe somebody has already claimed the url ?

Comment: @Shakehar you didn't even [try it](https://plus.google.com/+torbengb) before you commented, did you?

Comment: I was at my work place where social networks don't work, that's the reason its a comment :), still maybe some Google plus engineer shares your initials and has reserved it for himself but hasn't gotten around to creating it  ;)

Comment: try using HTTPS - that can sometimes bypass restrictions

Comment: naah, that might work for high schools not here :)

Comment: It works in this bank. _#justsaying_ :-)

Comment: haha :) maybe I should join it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Google is currently denying all custom url claims, even though they pretend to give you a choice. See the [top comment on th post introducing the option](https://plus.google.com/+googleplus/posts/8C5oKFUKLVs) in the first place.